# Navigation bar placement and design

Tags: html, css, nav

I saw this really nice design from Webey that put there navigation bar centralized, panning across the entire page and at the top of the webpage.

However I can't figure out how the bar was put at the top of the webpage
I'd greatly appreciate any help you can offer.
I don't have the rep to post images but I supplied links to the Nav bar I currently have, and the nav bar I was using as an example below.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciHP2.png
Current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqiE8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of how to do it **[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/aShQL/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="fixed">
    My fixed bar
</div>

<div id="targets">
    <div id="target-1">
        <a href="#target-2">Jump to target 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="target-2">
        <a href="#target-3">Jump to target 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="target-3">
        <a href="#target-4">Jump to target 4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="target-4">
        <a href="#target-5">Jump to target 5</a>
    </div>
    <div id="target-5">
        <a href="#target-1">Jump to target 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:50px 0 0;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:1em;
}
a { color:#333; }

#fixed { 
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;    
    background:#000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#targets div {
    height:400px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

#target-1 { background:#888; }
#target-2 { background:#999; }
#target-3 { background:#AAA; }
#target-4 { background:#BBB; }
#target-5 { background:#CCC; }
```

an other one based in `position: fixed` for the nav-bar --> **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jaQFZ/166/)**

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help I couldn't for the life of me figure out what  I wasn't doing wrong!